# Using CSS for a Slider font resize

Tags: css, responsive

I am using *Avada* theme and want to resize the words on the sliders I have on the homepage so that they are still a large part of the slider when it's on mobile, because now they shrink to be really small and hard to read.

I researched and the new version of the theme fixes this. However, I wanted to know why my code below didn't fix it.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.sliders-container {font-size: 100px};}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You *very rarely* want to change the font size expressed in `px`. In CSS, `1px` is a *relative* unit; it does not mean "one physical pixel". A font declared `16px` will have about the same size on all devices, unless something else forces it to be rendered bigger or smaller.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I'll try removing that, thanks

Comment: font-size in px is absolutely fine, I use it all the time. The reason your media query isn't working I would guess is because you're testing on a retina screen perhaps?

Comment: This is correct, I have tried it on an iPhone 6 and 7 screen but not an android. Is there something special you have to do if it's a retina display?

Comment: I don't represent the company in any way, but a good way to test is to use browserstack.com.